# Can't Form DataFrame from Parallel Offset Output

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, linestring, data-frame

I've been developing code to take a .csv with lat-long coords and convert them to LineStrings before creating parallel offsets for them. This has been working so far, but yesterday after clearing my variables, I started running into an error when running my code.

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df = pd.read_csv("***/Kingsboro Rd NE.csv")
df = df.drop_duplicates()

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.lng, df.lat)]
df['geometry'] = geometry
df['agg'] = 1
df_line = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.groupby(['agg'])['geometry'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x.tolist())), geometry='geometry')
df_line = df_line.set_crs("EPSG:4326")
df_line = df_line.to_crs("EPSG:2240")

df_offset_l = pd.DataFrame(df_line.iloc[0].geometry.parallel_offset(25, 'left', 2, mitre_limit = 100.0))
```

Everything runs fine until the final line, for which I get the following error:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

As I mentioned before, I have not been getting this error until yesterday, and I need it to work properly to perform the other data manipulation steps following this line of code.

Here's a sample of the input file:

| lat | long |
| --- | --- |
| 33.85556214 | -84.35139656 |
| 33.85569133 | -84.35140193 |
| 33.85556214 | -84.35139656 |
| 33.85553986 | -84.35136706 |
| 33.85550868 | -84.35134828 |

Comment: You try to create `DataFrame` or `GeoDataFrame`?

Answer (score 3):

`DataFrame` or `GeoDataFrame` needs an iterable parameter but you pass shapely object (`LineString`) to it. So you get that error.

Make offset line:

```
offset_line = df_line.iloc[0].geometry.parallel_offset(25, 'left', 2, mitre_limit = 100.0)
```

Then,

- If you need a `DataFrame` use this way:

  ```
  df_offset_l = pd.DataFrame({"geometry": [offset_line]})

  # OUTPUT (DataFrame)
  #     geometry
  # 0   LINESTRING (2240477.867 1402553.588, 2240476.3...
  ```
- If you need a `GeoDataFrame` use this way:

  ```
  df_offset_l = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"geometry": [offset_line]})

  # OUTPUT (GeoDataFrame)
  #     geometry
  # 0   LINESTRING (2240477.866711137 1402553.58829784...
  ```